# Can't select AID Card Manager when testing to send APDU

Tags: java, applet, javacard, apdu, pcsc

I am trying to load an applet into a smart card, before I wanted just to make a little test with the following code :

```
import javax.smartcardio.*;
import java.util.*;

public class TestSmartCardIO {

    public static String toString(byte[] bytes) {
        StringBuffer sbTmp = new StringBuffer();
        for(byte b : bytes){
            sbTmp.append(String.format("%X", b));
        }
        return sbTmp.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            TerminalFactory factory = TerminalFactory.getDefault();
            List terminals = factory.terminals().list();
            System.out.println("Terminals count: " + terminals.size());
            System.out.println("Terminals: " + terminals);

            // Get the first terminal in the list
            CardTerminal terminal = (CardTerminal) terminals.get(0);

            // Establish a connection with the card using
            // "T=0", "T=1", "T=CL" or "*"
            Card card = terminal.connect("*");
            System.out.println("Card: " + card);

            // Get ATR
            byte[] baATR = card.getATR().getBytes();
            System.out.println("ATR: " + TestSmartCardIO.toString(baATR) );

            CardChannel channel = card.getBasicChannel();

            /*SELECT Command
             See GlobalPlatform Card Specification (e.g. 2.2, section 11.9)
             CLA: 00
             INS: A4
             P1: 04 i.e. b3 is set to 1, means select by name
             P2: 00 i.e. first or only occurence
             Lc: 08 i.e. length of AID see below
             Data: A0 00 00 00 03 00 00 00
             AID of the card manager,
             in the future should change to A0 00 00 01 51 00 00*/

             byte[] baCommandAPDU = {(byte) 0x00, (byte) 0xA4, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0xA0, (byte) 0x00, 
                                    (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00};
            System.out.println("APDU >>>: " + TestSmartCardIO.toString(baCommandAPDU));

            ResponseAPDU r = channel.transmit(new CommandAPDU(baCommandAPDU));
            System.out.println("APDU <<<: " + TestSmartCardIO.toString(r.getBytes()));

            // Disconnect
            // true: reset the card after disconnecting card.

            card.disconnect(true);
        } catch(Exception ex)  {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

So I just wanted to test if the card is recognized and if I can send APDUs properly. I am trying to select the AID Card Manager by the APDU but I get :

```
Terminals count: 1
Terminals: [PC/SC terminal OT MicroSD smartcard Reader 1]
Card: PC/SC card in OT MicroSD smartcard Reader 1, protocol T=1, state OK
ATR: 3BDB96081B1FE451F83031C0641A181019005D
APDU >>>: 0A4408A00003000
APDU <<<: 6A82
```

And `SW1 = 6A` and `SW2 = 82` means that the card does not find the AID Card Manager... Is it normal ?
I don't really understand, I wonder if it is linked with the fact that the card uses the protocol `T = 1` ? Thank you very much for your help

Comment: This shouldn't be related to `T=1` vs. `T=0`, but to be sure, you could of course try `T=0` explicitly. I tried your program and it works fine, I get an expected long response with `0x9000` as status word. (Except that it should be `"%02X"` in `String.format()`, otherwise you will omit leading zeros for values <16.) Are you sure that your card is already in an OP life cycle state that has a card manager available? Are you sure that you got the AID of *your* card manager right? You could also remove some bytes and try a shorter partial SELECT command to find a match.

Comment: Well, how can I determine if my card is in an OP life cycle state that has a card manager ? I think it should but I don't know how to be sure about it...
I tried also to send the SELECT Command : `00A4040000` and I get the strange response : `6F6D847A00015100A562732F672A864886FC6B160C6A2A864886FC6B2211639672A864886FC6B364B692A864886FC6B4159F6E2A47905167823193220722249A801BF42801142425311434253114442531000000000009F651FF900` that I don't understand... Thank you very much for your consideration

Comment: BTW the AID of the card manager may vary between manufacturers and card generations. Your AID worked for only 1 of my cards, which is a Visa card issued by OCS (Oberthur Card Systems). It did not work for a Maestro card issued by G&D, and not for a MasterCard (issuer unknown to me).

Comment: That response is a normal response to SELECT Card Manager, it just looks a bit strange because of your `format` bug, the last bytes actually are `9000` (you see `90` and `0` because you forgot the `02` for `%02X`).

Comment: Well, I modified it and your right, so I can send APDUs to my card. Do I have to conclude that I don't give to my card the right AID of the card manager ?

Comment: For some cards, the Card Manager can be selected by simply selecting the "first thing" by sending `00A4040000`. But it doesn't work for all cards. Here it only worked with the Visa Card from OCS, not with the Maestro card from G&D (I believe in the case of this card the OS is actually from Gemalto) and not with the MasterCard.

Comment: From the FCI you received for the empty select command, you can see that the AID of the card manager is actually `A0 00 00 01 51 00 00` (contained in tag 0x84).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Previously Global Platform borrowed the [RID](http://www.ansi.org/other_services/registration_programs/rid.aspx?menuid=10) (the first 5 bytes of the AID) from VISA. This is because of historical reasons. Global Platform is now a separate entity but Open Platform - as it was once called - was started by (at least) VISA. There are [many RID's registered](https://www.eftlab.com.au/index.php/site-map/knowledge-base/212-emv-rid).

However from what I understood, VISA did not want to use Global Platform to use their RID anymore. So a new RID was requested. Instead of the rather low `A000000003` RID, Global Platform now used their own: `A000000151` RID. Another difference is that the last bytes (which can be anything, up to 15 - 5 = 10 bytes, specified by the organization) now consists of two bytes instead of three. Some OS versions actually get that wrong and still use three `00` bytes.

So you previously had `A000000003 000000` for Open Platform and earlier GP implementations and for later cards or Global Platform specifications you have `A000000151 0000` to select the card manager. The handling of SELECT is not completely clear from ISO/IEC 7816-4. Generally though if you provide a smaller AID (of at least 5 bytes) within SELECT by NAME then a matching application will be selected.

Answer (score 1):

Just a friendly reminder, that working with globalplatform/javacards "in the wild" can be a daunting task, getting things right depends on many factors. You might want to have a look at [GlobalPlatformPro](https://github.com/martinpaljak/GlobalPlatformPro) (formerly known as GPJ) for this.

It should hide many of the annoying technical details (like trying to figure out the ISD AID) from your daily tasks while also providing you with the source code to study things in detail, if you want to.